# How do I set up Bootstrap on my React app using npm localy?

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-bootstrap

I installed Bootstrap and jQuery using npm and I did this in my App.js file:

```
const $ = require('jquery'); 
global.jQuery = $; 
require('bootstrap');
```

This is the ref link in my index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" link="./dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

I am using webpack.

Comment: You might start by reading through the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/webpack/

Answer (score 0):

import the styles of the bootstrap in your index.js file like:

```
 import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

or

```
 import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

I suppose you have installed bootstrap like:

```
 npm install --save bootstrap
```

Or you can use the following CDN for bootstrap and add it in the index.html file:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: I get this error    Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

Answer (score -1):

1) Install react-bootstrap

`npm install --save react-bootstrap`

2) include the latest styles from the CDN

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and use it like,

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Comment: My goal is not to include the href like that, but to include it locally from the bootstrap I installed in my app using npm. But when I import the path it doesn't work. Can you help me with that please?

Comment: And I don't want to import react-bootstrap, but just bootstrap

Comment: @sara: can you please check if you can see bootstrap in your node_modules folder ?

Comment: Yes, it's in my node_modules folder